Late 2000s-early 2010s - Movie about mercenaries settling scores
Looking for a late 2000s-early 2010s movie about mercenaries settling scores.
I have no clue whatsoever about the actors involved, but I can tell it was about two rival gangs of mercenaries/former military/professional hitmen taking one another's members out in some sort of revenge cycle going back and forth. The setting was the present, in the 2000s.
For a long time, I thought it was Killer Elite with De Niro and Statham, but I realized the scene I'm looking for is not featured in there, hence my question here.
I have a very clear recollection of a single (shocking) scene involving a dialogue between one of the cold hitmen (from the "good" team if I may use that word, still ruthless cold killers overall), where one of the targets, some former Eastern European killer with a strong accent, bald with a nice suit, full mafia style and a little drunk, is tracked down to a nightclub where he is first approached by the "good" killer while he's drinking and cracking jokes with some younger guy next to him, apparently his friend at the night out.
After that, there's a brief initial exchange in the club, where the "good" hitman starts lecturing his target a bit and ends up showing his intent of outright killing him, asks him something along the lines of "aren't you ashamed of your deeds" to which the bald guy (a Serb I believe, though again, unsure) responds with a shockingly vile "I killed babies" with a bored face, I suppose to basically affirm he has no moral compass nor does he care about any judgment. He then somehow accepts to "take it outside," apparently not realizing the seriousness of his situation at that point, and the mid-long haired clueless young American friend goes out with him too, despite the killer's warning not to get him involved, but the baldie insists "he's my friend" or something like that, implying he should come along.
They then get to a nearby swamp or small pond (?) with high foliage around it, a more quiet place far enough from the club (possibly via a short car or Hummer ride, but it's really too vague for me to tell, sorry).
After some more harsh words, the hitman shoots him, and then the clueless "friend" starts crying and begging, realizing too late what he got himself into by following the pair. The killer then scolds him too for being so irresponsible and shoots him as well as a witness (I am 99% positive he cries and gets mercilessly killed).
I believe Statham or De Niro are involved, but I'm not sure (and that's what tricked me into thinking Killer Elite was the answer, as its theme and tone were pretty close to the implacable movie I'm looking for).
I hope that's enough for you connoisseurs to help me. :)

Maybe one of the Expendables movies? Those had a few different mercenaries up against the "heroes" - which included Statham as one of the main leaders of the good guys

Indeed I tried watching this one to make sure it could match, but no luck, sadly. Thanks for trying to help though.
